# how to download mulitple .PDF files in java

Tags: java

OnClick of button on JSP Page, I am trying to download more than one pdf one by one using java code but not able to done it and Using Following snippet code for the same

```
     Document document[]=  new Document[20];
             httpServletResponse.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
                "attachment;filename=welcome.pdf");
                httpServletResponse.setContentType("application/pdf");
                try{
                    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
                    {
                    System.out.println(i);
                    document[i]=new Document();
                    PdfWriter.getInstance(document[i], httpServletResponse.getOutputStream());
                    document[i].open();
                    document[i].add(new Paragraph("Hello Prakash"));
                    document[i].add(new Paragraph(new Date().toString()));
                    document[i].close();
                    } 
                     }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

It is not working and alaways only one .PDF file is downloading, anyone help me out?

Comment: You cannot download multiple files in a single request. A workaround would be to put them into a zip file.

Comment: I already did this by using a zip file that contains all the pdf files

Comment: sry,i can't zip it my requirement should download one by one

Comment: Perhaps then you should look at the browser-side technologies like JavaScript, Flash, etc. to help you initiate multiple requests. As @Thilo said, it can't be a single request: one request - one document.

Comment: I understood  this but how to done this in java code

Comment: Be aware though that 1) you may be misinterpreting the requirement, and 2) the requirements aren't always feasible (i.e. downloading multiple documents in one click isn't what a normal user would expect from a browser).

Comment: Since they're PDFs, one could instead of zipping also merge the PDFs into one large PDF using for example the iText library. Then at least you can trigger that one PDF to open in a PDF viewer directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One could prepare a page, that does multiple requests to the server, every one which of downloads a PDF. This is not so nice a user experience.

I would use a zip file containing all PDFs:

```
response.setContentType("application/zip"); // application/octet-stream
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"all.zip\"");
try (ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(response.getOutputStream())) {
     for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
         ZipEntry ze = new ZipEntry("document-" + i + ".pdf");
         zos.putNextEntry(ze);

         // It would be nice to write the PDF immediately to zos.
         // However then you must take care to not close the PDF (and zos),
         // but just flush (= write all buffered).
         //PdfWriter pw = PdfWriter.getInstance(document[i], zos);
         //...
         //pw.flush(); // Not closing pw/zos

         // Or write the PDF to memory:
         ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ...
         PdfWriter pw = PdfWriter.getInstance(document[i], baos);
         ...
         pw.close();
         byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
         zos.write(baos, 0, baos.length);

         zos.closeEntry();
     }
}
```

***Just read, you cannot use ZIP download.***

Maybe you might use HTML5 offering a nicer download experience (progress bars?).

Comment: Thanks joop, but i couldn't understand your Code could please provid exact code

Comment: I have made to code pick the second alternative: write the PDF to a ByteArrayOutputStream, so one gets a `byte[]` of the file contents to write to the zip. // The try-with-resources is for Java 7. Otherwise one needs to call `zos.close()` at the end.

Comment: joop,,whenever i doing code of this PdfWriter pw = PdfWriter.getInstance(document[i], baos); here document is throwing error like "The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to Document" how can i resolve this?

Comment: I copied your code; from the error message I think `document` without `[i]` suffices and already is a Document, not an array of documents.